# Facets with 40000+ taxonomy terms make page load slow

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms, search

I am running Drupal 8.8.1. I have Search API Solr 8.x-2.2 and Facets 8.x-1.3. I have 40,804 taxonomy terms. I added this taxonomy term in my solr index as string. I already have a view page . I added a facet and attached this to my facet source (search_api:views_page__legislative_issuances__page_1) which is the view I want this facet to be shown. I tried various combinations of soft limit of 50 on showing amount of results and also hard limit of 50 on Display no more than this number of facet items. It seems that when I go to this view, all taxonomy terms are loaded first and then the limited facet (50 items) shows up. This loading time takes time. When I disable this in my facet in my block, (since I need to put them into the block so that it will show in the page if enabled) the loading time is faster. I want this taxonomy term term to show up in my view but I want this page to load faster. Am I missing something in order for me to achieve faster loading time? Thanks in advance!

My exported search index configuration:

```
    uuid: a44e59a4-8d7a-41e6-b3f4-9744ca69237d
    langcode: en
    status: true
    dependencies:
      module:
        - search_api_solr
        - taxonomy
        - node
        - search_api
      config:
        - field.storage.node.field_cn_issuance_was_passed
        - field.storage.node.field_date_of_approval
        - field.storage.node.field_executive_issuance_type
        - field.storage.node.field_full_title_of_issuance
        - field.storage.node.field_issuance_category
        - field.storage.node.field_legislative_issuance_type
        - field.storage.node.field_short_title_of_issuance
        - field.storage.node.field_subjects
        - field.storage.node.field_title_sort_of_issuance
        - search_api.server.issuances_only
    third_party_settings:
      search_api_solr:
        finalize: false
        commit_before_finalize: false
        commit_after_finalize: false
    id: issuances_only
    name: 'Issuances Only'
    description: ''
    read_only: false
    field_settings:
      field_date_of_approval:
        label: 'Date of Approval'
        datasource_id: 'entity:node'
        property_path: field_date_of_approval
        type: date
        dependencies:
          config:
            - field.storage.node.field_date_of_approval
      field_full_title_of_issuance:
        label: 'Full Title of Issuance'
        datasource_id: 'entity:node'
        property_path: field_full_title_of_issuance
        type: text
        dependencies:
          config:
            - field.storage.node.field_full_title_of_issuance
      field_short_title_of_issuance:
        label: 'Short Title of Issuance'
        datasource_id: 'entity:node'
        property_path: field_short_title_of_issuance
        type: text
        dependencies:
          config:
            - field.storage.node.field_short_title_of_issuance
      field_title_sort_of_issuance:
        label: 'Title sort of issuance'
        datasource_id: 'entity:node'
        property_path: field_title_sort_of_issuance
        type: string
        dependencies:
          config:
            - field.storage.node.field_title_sort_of_issuance
      name_executive_issuance_type:
        label: 'Executive Issuance Type » Taxonomy term » Name'
        datasource_id: 'entity:node'
        property_path: 'field_executive_issuance_type:entity:name'
        type: string
        dependencies:
          config:
            - field.storage.node.field_executive_issuance_type
          module:
            - taxonomy
            - taxonomy
      name_issuance_category:
        label: 'Issuance Category » Taxonomy term » Name'
        datasource_id: 'entity:node'
        property_path: 'field_issuance_category:entity:name'
        type: string
        dependencies:
          config:
            - field.storage.node.field_issuance_category
          module:
            - taxonomy
            - taxonomy
      name_legislative_issuance_type:
        label: 'Legislative Issuance Type » Taxonomy term » Name'
        datasource_id: 'entity:node'
        property_path: 'field_legislative_issuance_type:entity:name'
        type: string
        dependencies:
          config:
            - field.storage.node.field_legislative_issuance_type
          module:
            - taxonomy
            - taxonomy
      name_subjects:
        label: 'Subjects » Taxonomy term » Name'
        datasource_id: 'entity:node'
        property_path: 'field_subjects:entity:name'
        type: string
        dependencies:
          config:
            - field.storage.node.field_subjects
          module:
            - taxonomy
            - taxonomy
      node_grants:
        label: 'Node access information'
        property_path: search_api_node_grants
        type: string
        indexed_locked: true
        type_locked: true
        hidden: true
      status:
        label: status
        datasource_id: 'entity:node'
        property_path: status
        type: boolean
        indexed_locked: true
        type_locked: true
        dependencies:
          module:
            - node
      tid:
        label: 'Congress Name Issuance was Passed » Taxonomy term » Term ID'
        datasource_id: 'entity:node'
        property_path: 'field_cn_issuance_was_passed:entity:tid'
        type: integer
        dependencies:
          config:
            - field.storage.node.field_cn_issuance_was_passed
          module:
            - taxonomy
            - taxonomy
      title:
        label: Title
        datasource_id: 'entity:node'
        property_path: title
        type: text
        dependencies:
          module:
            - node
      uid:
        label: uid
        datasource_id: 'entity:node'
        property_path: uid
        type: integer
        indexed_locked: true
        type_locked: true
        dependencies:
          module:
            - node
    datasource_settings:
      'entity:node':
        bundles:
          default: false
          selected:
            - issuances
        languages:
          default: true
          selected: {  }
    processor_settings:
      add_url: {  }
      aggregated_field: {  }
      content_access:
        weights:
          preprocess_query: -30
      double_quote_workaround:
        all_fields: false
        fields:
          - field_full_title_of_issuance
          - field_short_title_of_issuance
          - field_title_sort_of_issuance
          - name_executive_issuance_type
          - name_issuance_category
          - name_legislative_issuance_type
          - title
        replacement: '|9999999998|'
        weights:
          postprocess_query: 0
          preprocess_index: -15
          preprocess_query: -15
      highlight:
        highlight: always
        highlight_partial: false
        excerpt: true
        excerpt_length: 256
        exclude_fields: {  }
        prefix: '<strong>'
        suffix: '</strong>'
        weights:
          postprocess_query: 0
      html_filter:
        all_fields: false
        fields:
          - field_full_title_of_issuance
          - field_short_title_of_issuance
          - field_title_sort_of_issuance
          - name_executive_issuance_type
          - name_issuance_category
          - name_legislative_issuance_type
          - title
        title: true
        alt: true
        tags:
          b: 2
          em: 1
          h1: 5
          h2: 3
          h3: 2
          strong: 2
          u: 1
        weights:
          preprocess_index: -15
          preprocess_query: -15
      rendered_item: {  }
      solr_date_range:
        weights:
          preprocess_index: 0
    tracker_settings:
      default:
        indexing_order: fifo
    options:
      index_directly: true
      cron_limit: 50
    server: issuances_only
```

Here is my views exported configuration:

```
uuid: 44695087-d707-4a76-87b5-5d86cc232206
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.node.field_date_of_approval
    - search_api.index.issuances_only
  module:
    - datetime
    - search_api
id: legislative_issuances
label: 'Legislative Issuances'
module: views
description: 'Legislative Issuances'
tag: ''
base_table: search_api_index_issuances_only
base_field: search_api_id
display:
  default:
    display_plugin: default
    id: default
    display_title: Master
    position: 0
    display_options:
      access:
        type: none
        options: {  }
      cache:
        type: tag
        options: {  }
      query:
        type: views_query
        options:
          bypass_access: false
          skip_access: false
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Apply
          reset_button: true
          reset_button_label: Reset
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Sort by'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
      pager:
        type: full
        options:
          items_per_page: 50
          offset: 0
          id: 0
          total_pages: null
          tags:
            previous: ‹‹
            next: ››
            first: '« First'
            last: 'Last »'
          expose:
            items_per_page: true
            items_per_page_label: 'Items per page'
            items_per_page_options: '5, 10, 25, 50'
            items_per_page_options_all: false
            items_per_page_options_all_label: '- All -'
            offset: false
            offset_label: Offset
          quantity: 9
      style:
        type: default
      row:
        type: search_api
        options:
          view_modes:
            'entity:node':
              issuances: teaser
      fields:
        field_date_of_approval:
          table: search_api_index_issuances_only
          field: field_date_of_approval
          id: field_date_of_approval
          entity_type: null
          entity_field: null
          plugin_id: search_api_field
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: datetime_default
          settings: {  }
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          field_rendering: true
          fallback_handler: search_api
          fallback_options:
            link_to_item: false
            use_highlighting: false
            multi_type: separator
            multi_separator: ', '
      filters:
        name_issuance_category:
          id: name_issuance_category
          table: search_api_index_issuances_only
          field: name_issuance_category
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          operator: '='
          value:
            min: ''
            max: ''
            value: 'Legislative Issuance'
          group: 1
          exposed: false
          expose:
            operator_id: name_issuance_category_op
            label: 'Issuance Category » Taxonomy term » Name'
            description: null
            use_operator: false
            operator: name_issuance_category_op
            operator_limit_selection: false
            operator_list: {  }
            identifier: name_issuance_category
            required: false
            remember: false
            multiple: false
            remember_roles:
              authenticated: authenticated
            placeholder: null
            min_placeholder: null
            max_placeholder: null
          is_grouped: false
          group_info:
            label: ''
            description: ''
            identifier: ''
            optional: true
            widget: select
            multiple: false
            remember: false
            default_group: All
            default_group_multiple: {  }
            group_items: {  }
          plugin_id: search_api_string
        name_legislative_issuance_type:
          id: name_legislative_issuance_type
          table: search_api_index_issuances_only
          field: name_legislative_issuance_type
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          operator: '='
          value:
            min: ''
            max: ''
            value: ''
          group: 1
          exposed: true
          expose:
            operator_id: name_legislative_issuance_type_op
            label: 'Legislative Issuance Type » Taxonomy term » Name'
            description: null
            use_operator: false
            operator: name_legislative_issuance_type_op
            operator_limit_selection: false
            operator_list: {  }
            identifier: name_legislative_issuance_type
            required: false
            remember: false
            multiple: false
            remember_roles:
              authenticated: authenticated
            placeholder: null
            min_placeholder: null
            max_placeholder: null
          is_grouped: true
          group_info:
            label: 'Legislative Issuance Type'
            description: ''
            identifier: name_legislative_issuance_type
            optional: true
            widget: select
            multiple: false
            remember: false
            default_group: All
            default_group_multiple: {  }
            group_items:
              1:
                title: 'Republic Act'
                operator: '='
                value:
                  value: 'Republic Act'
                  min: ''
                  max: ''
              2:
                title: 'Batas Pambansa'
                operator: '='
                value:
                  value: 'Batas Pambansa'
                  min: ''
                  max: ''
              3:
                title: 'Commonwealth Act'
                operator: '='
                value:
                  value: 'Commonwealth Act'
                  min: ''
                  max: ''
              4:
                title: Act
                operator: '='
                value:
                  value: ACT
                  min: ''
                  max: ''
              5:
                title: 'Concurrent Resolution'
                operator: '='
                value:
                  value: 'Concurrent Resolution'
                  min: ''
                  max: ''
              6:
                title: 'Joint Resolution'
                operator: '='
                value:
                  value: 'Joint Resolution'
                  min: ''
                  max: ''
              7:
                title: 'Senate Resolution'
                operator: '='
                value:
                  value: 'Senate Resolution'
                  min: ''
                  max: ''
          plugin_id: search_api_string
        field_date_of_approval:
          id: field_date_of_approval
          table: search_api_index_issuances_only
          field: field_date_of_approval
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          operator: '='
          value:
            min: ''
            max: ''
            value: ''
            type: date_year
          group: 1
          exposed: true
          expose:
            operator_id: field_date_of_approval_op
            label: 'Year of Approval'
            description: ''
            use_operator: false
            operator: field_date_of_approval_op
            operator_limit_selection: false
            operator_list: {  }
            identifier: field_date_of_approval
            required: false
            remember: false
            multiple: false
            remember_roles:
              authenticated: authenticated
              anonymous: '0'
              content_author: '0'
              content_approver: '0'
              maestro_example: '0'
              site_administrator: '0'
            placeholder: ''
            min_placeholder: ''
            max_placeholder: ''
          is_grouped: false
          group_info:
            label: ''
            description: ''
            identifier: ''
            optional: true
            widget: select
            multiple: false
            remember: false
            default_group: All
            default_group_multiple: {  }
            group_items: {  }
          plugin_id: search_api_date
      sorts:
        field_title_sort_of_issuance:
          id: field_title_sort_of_issuance
          table: search_api_index_issuances_only
          field: field_title_sort_of_issuance
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          order: DESC
          exposed: false
          expose:
            label: ''
          plugin_id: search_api
      title: 'Legislative Issuances'
      header:
        result:
          id: result
          table: views
          field: result
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          empty: false
          content: 'Displaying @start - @end of @total'
          plugin_id: result
      footer: {  }
      empty: {  }
      relationships: {  }
      arguments: {  }
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url
        - url.query_args
      tags:
        - 'config:field.storage.node.field_date_of_approval'
  block_1:
    display_plugin: block
    id: block_1
    display_title: Block
    position: 2
    display_options:
      display_extenders: {  }
      style:
        type: default
      defaults:
        style: false
        row: false
        pager: false
      row:
        type: fields
      pager:
        type: full
        options:
          items_per_page: 5
          offset: 0
          id: 0
          total_pages: null
          expose:
            items_per_page: false
            items_per_page_label: 'Items per page'
            items_per_page_options: '5, 10, 25, 50'
            items_per_page_options_all: false
            items_per_page_options_all_label: '- All -'
            offset: false
            offset_label: Offset
          tags:
            previous: '‹ Previous'
            next: 'Next ›'
            first: '« First'
            last: 'Last »'
          quantity: 9
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url
        - url.query_args
      tags:
        - 'config:field.storage.node.field_date_of_approval'
  page_1:
    display_plugin: page
    id: page_1
    display_title: Page
    position: 1
    display_options:
      display_extenders: {  }
      path: legislative-issuances
      cache:
        type: search_api_tag
        options: {  }
      defaults:
        cache: false
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url
        - url.query_args
      tags:
        - 'config:field.storage.node.field_date_of_approval'
```

Lastly, my facet configuration:

```
uuid: 94a534c5-2b1b-4511-9d98-ce53ae6bed62
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - search_api.index.issuances_only
    - views.view.executive_issuances_search
  module:
    - search_api
id: subjects
name: Subjects
url_alias: subjects
weight: 0
min_count: 1
show_only_one_result: false
field_identifier: name_subjects
facet_source_id: 'search_api:views_page__executive_issuances_search__page_1'
widget:
  type: links
  config:
    show_numbers: true
    soft_limit: 50
    soft_limit_settings:
      show_less_label: 'Show less'
      show_more_label: 'Show more'
query_operator: or
use_hierarchy: false
expand_hierarchy: false
enable_parent_when_child_gets_disabled: true
hard_limit: 0
exclude: false
only_visible_when_facet_source_is_visible: true
processor_configs:
  active_widget_order:
    processor_id: active_widget_order
    weights:
      sort: 20
    settings:
      sort: DESC
  count_widget_order:
    processor_id: count_widget_order
    weights:
      sort: 30
    settings:
      sort: DESC
  display_value_widget_order:
    processor_id: display_value_widget_order
    weights:
      sort: 40
    settings:
      sort: ASC
  url_processor_handler:
    processor_id: url_processor_handler
    weights:
      pre_query: 50
      build: 15
    settings: {  }
empty_behavior:
  behavior: none
show_title: false
```

Comment: This sort of thing can be tricky to debug & fix. You could try switching the views page to a time based cache. Maybe the 40k taxonomy terms are loading too many cache tags when the view renders. Otherwise, a custom block that loads the facets programatically, and then that block has its own custom cache? Tricky to do though. Another possibility is to try applying this patch: https://www.drupal.org/project/facets/issues/2939710